# Error message while trying to export data from SQL Server 2014 to Microsoft Excel?

Tags: sql, excel, export-to-excel, calculated-columns, error-reporting

I'm using sql export wizard to transfer data from sql to excel. At the end of the process I get an error message

> Data Flow Task 1: Column "colname" cannot be found at the datasource.

I did some research and others suggested to check the box next **Enable identity insert** by clicking on **Edit Mapping** however when I click on **Edit Mapping** there is no option to **Enable identity insert**.

The table is too large to copy it and paste it into excel file... Any help would be great.

Comment: Can you just run a `SELECT *` query and export the results to csv and open that in Excel, or otherwise convert it to Excel?

Comment: @ Kyle- I tried but I wasn't able to maintain data integrity since the table I have already have commas.

Comment: So your source is SQLServer, and your destination is excel? You shouldn't have any need for identity inserts there. I'm assuming you are using a query as your datasource. Does it run properly when you run it in SSMS against the database properly?

Comment: @  LordBaconPants- So your source is SQLServer, and your destination is excel? That's right. Thanks for the info. Not sure what's causing the error message then.

Comment: How are you getting your data from the database? Have you chosen to get it by a query, or all of the table?

Comment: @ LordBaconPants- trying to get all of the table.

Comment: I'm not sure what is going on there then I'm afraid. It feels like it is trying to get something that isn't there. If chose to do it as a query with `select * from table`, what does that do for you?

Comment: @ LordBaconPants- Just tried to use a query and got the same error message.

Comment: Are you sure you have SQL set as your source and Excel set as your destination? it sounds like you have them in reverse as that message should only appear if trying to import from an excel file into a sql table that doesn't have the same column name as one in your excel file.

Comment: The other thing to check is if you are exporting from SQL to an already existing Excel sheet, you must have the same column names in the excel sheet as in SQL, or at least change the mappings, or you could get that error there.

Comment: So what happens if you use `SELECT [colname] FROM Table` and preview that? If that works, what happens when you run it? Please post your full query

Comment: @ Darthchai- yes I have sql set as my source and no issues with the number of columns.

Comment: Nick.McDermaid- If I use SELECT [ApplicationName] From [TEST_DB].[dbo].[Test4] and preview the results I don't see any issues and I can view the data.

Comment: @Curious Can you export as a tab delimited text? Or does the data set contain tabs as well? If you can run the query, then you should be able to find a way to export the query. Have you considered querying straight into Excel with VBA/ADO?